# Create a new dictionary based on 2 dictionaries with not same key name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following 2 dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'imgsss/modifiedmerged/modifiedmerged-2.png': 3, 'imgsss/modifiedmerged/modifiedmerged-4.png': 5}


dict2 = {"form1": "POLICY NUMBER COMMERCIAL GENERAL", "form2": "ACP GLDO7285650787"}
```

I want to create a new dictionary based on the above 2 dictionaries. Basically the value of the `dict1` should be the last digit of the key of `dict2`. Rest everything should be same. So the output dictionary should be:

```
op_dict = {
    "form3": "POLICY NUMBER COMMERCIAL GENERAL", 
    "form5": "ACP GLDO7285650787"
}
```

Basically the first element of `dict1` should be matched with the 1st element of `dict2`, 2nd element of `dict1` with 2nd element of `dict2` and so on. The `form` keyword will remain constant but the digit after may change. Similary the values of `dict1` may change.

I tried the following code:

```
op_dict = {}
for k, v in dict1.items():
    for k1, v1 in dict2.items():
        op_dict[f'form{str(v)}'] = v1
```

but it is giving incorrect output:

```
op_dict = {'form3': 'ACP GLDO7285650787', 'form5': 'ACP GLDO7285650787'}
```

Comment: How do you decide which element of `dict1` to match with each element of `dict2`?  Your attempt makes *every* possible match, ending with the last one don for a given `form`.

Comment: Since dictionaries are ordered, the first element of `dict1` should be matched with the 1st element of `dict2`, 2nd element of `dict1` with 2nd element of `dict2` and so on.

Comment: Then there should be a single loop, not nested loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With dict comprehension (assuming that the 2nd dict prefixes are known as `form`):

```
op_dict = {f'{k[:4]}{n}': v for n, (k, v) in zip(dict1.values(), dict2.items())}
```

---

```
{'form3': 'POLICY NUMBER COMMERCIAL GENERAL', 'form5': 'ACP GLDO7285650787'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version of @RomanPerekhrest answer:

```
op_dict = {f'form{n}': v for n, v in zip(dict1.values(), dict2.values())}
```

---

```
{'form3': 'POLICY NUMBER COMMERCIAL GENERAL', 'form5': 'ACP GLDO7285650787'}
```